# State is not synced with localStorage

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm using `ngrx-store-localstorage` package to sync the state between localstorage and `ngrx/store`. I set it up like it's showed on Github but it doesn't work. I login easily, the state in `ngrx` devtools is updated but token in localstorage is still null as the initial state is set.

Here is the github link of the package, code and everything: 
https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage

Here is my code:

```js
export function localStorageSyncReducer(auth: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return localStorageSync({ keys: ['token'], rehydrate: true })(auth);
}
const metaReducers: Array<MetaReducer<any, any>> = [localStorageSyncReducer];
```

This is also set..

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers })
```

I tried also to add `reducers.auth` in the bracket at the end, then it works but there is only 'token' property in whole application state.

Answer (score 0):

I would try by putting this in my code:

```
export const getAuthState = createFeatureSelector<State.auth>('auth')
```

and then change the params to:

```
{ keys: ['auth'], rehydrate: true }
```

This should work for the whole state.